# Considerations if I were to lengthen session expiration dates at some interval if the client stays active?

Tags: authentication, session-management

Our API is protected with sessions that are stored and checked from the db (IE not signed JWTs from a client), and have an expiration stored in the db.

As of now it never updates the expiration, but I'd like for clients that ping the server at some interval to stay logged in.

I haven't heard of this so I just wanted to make sure I wasn't over looking some massive flaw.

So options.

1. Every time they hit an endpoint, bump up their expiration to say 1 hr from now. That's a bit excessive though.
2. To slow down the db updates, I could say that if they ping within 15 min. of expiry, I'll refresh it for another hour.
3. Something better?

Or are there any security holes I'm missing?

Comment: If somebody gets a token, then can keep sending requests to keep the session valid?

Comment: @Limit Good suggestion, I've been considering that too since asking the question, and am considering refresh tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, the biggest problem here is that if someone gets a session token, they simply can send periodic requests and keep the session running.

Also once a session has expired. Just mark it expired. Don't let a session renew on another ping. (I am assuming that these sessions are not like different users on same machine. In that case, it could also be the case that a user forgets to log out and another user logs in and gets access even after the session has expired)

You can refer the [OWASP cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Session_Expiration) on ways to handle session expiration.